# How to calculate a running total in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In `foreach` in a MVC view, is it possible to calculate a running total of the `Amount` value?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</td>          
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)</td>
        <td> // here Item.Amount, should sum based on previous</td>
     </tr>
}
```

Is it possible here in view or I need any method in controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you - Yes

```
@{ decimal runningTotal = 0M; } // assumes Total is typeof decimal
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    runningTotal += item.Amount
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</td>          
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)</td>
        <td>@runningTotal</td>
     </tr>
}
```

Should you - No

Create a view model to represent what you want to display in the view (i.e. include a `public decimal RunningTotal { get; set; }` property in addition to properties `ID` and `Amount`, and do the calculation in the controller where it belongs, so that in the view its simply

```
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RunningTotal)</td>
```

Note this also gives you the flexibility to apply a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute to format the value in the view.

Answer (score 1):

In your case is better to use "for" loop

```
@for (int i = 0;i<Model.Count();i++)
{
    var modelItem = Model[i];
    var calculatedField = modelItem.Amount;
    if (i>0)
    {
       calculatedField = Model[i-1].Amount;
    }
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</td>          
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)</td>
        <td> @calculatedField </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Didn't the runningTotal for an item should include all items before **and** the current item?